# How to handle unique session(One user session)using Node.js express session?

Tags: node.js, express, session

I need your help to get solution of the below query

How can I prevent a user to be logged in a system from two different browser concurrently?

Say a user has logged in on Firefox, If the same user logged in again from another browser like Chrome on the same or different machine, the session on Firefox should be destroyed and user should remain active in Chrome.

I am using express session in Node.js

Do I need some sort of database to store sessions or it can be achieved with express session alone?

Anxiously waiting for your suggestions

Comment: Anyone could please shed some light in this query

Answer (score 0):

@Gurpinder you have to use a DB for this. Make sure you have a unique element that uniquely defines a user. And for that specific user, map a sessionId alongside within that unique Id in DB.

Once with the same unique Id, another login request is made. Destroy the previous session and save the new one.

Let's suppose we have a table/collection with the name Session, once the login is done do the following.

```
Session.find({ 
            userId : userData.userId
        }).remove(function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                logger.error(error);
                callback(null);
            }
            else{
                that.storeSession(userData, callback);
            }
        });
```

Step 1: Find if a session already exists

Step 2: Remove if exist

Step 3: Create a new session.